# What is the difference between advertised.listeners and bootstrap.servers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to configure kafka so client can connect to it.
What is the difference between advertised.listeners and bootstrap.servers in kafka configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bootstrap.servers` parameter is used only for initial connection to **cluster**. After this initial connection is established, Kafka returns `advertised.listeners` which is ip/port list that is used to connect to **broker(s)**.

This image can be helpful to understand the concept:

[image]

Note: `advertised.host.name` is deprecated, you can assume that as `advertised.listeners`

For more information you can check [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/):

> **bootstrap.servers**: A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing
>   the initial connection to the Kafka cluster. The client will make use
>   of all servers irrespective of which servers are specified here for
>   bootstrapping—this list only impacts the initial hosts used to
>   discover the full set of servers. This list should be in the form
>   host1:port1,host2:port2,.... Since these servers are just used for the
>   initial connection to discover the full cluster membership (which may
>   change dynamically), this list need not contain the full set of
>   servers (you may want more than one, though, in case a server is
>   down).
>
> **advertised.listeners**: Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to
>   use, if different than the listeners config property. In IaaS
>   environments, this may need to be different from the interface to
>   which the broker binds. If this is not set, the value for listeners
>   will be used. Unlike listeners it is not valid to advertise the
>   0.0.0.0 meta-address.

Reference for image: https://www.udemy.com/course/kafka-cluster-setup/

Comment: there is a parameter : listeners. Seems its the same as bootstrap.servers ?

Comment: @voipp Listeners are what interfaces Kafka binds to. On the other hand you can think bootstrap.servers as ip-host/port of kafka servers (brokers) in cluster. By the way listeners is broker side config parameter, bootstrap.servers is producer/consumer side parameter.

Comment: @h-Ç-t when i connect to a broker first time, how it figures out what host:port it should return to me? There are several values in advertised.listeners

Comment: @voipp all of them are returned. You can check this [link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

`bootstrap.servers` is a list of broker(s) that you provide your client with to connect to the Kafka cluster.

`advertised.listeners` is the host&port of each broker that the client is provided with on the initial connection to the `bootstrap.server`. When the client connects to brokers subsequently it will use *these* and *not* the `bootstrap.server`, which is why it is so important that you set `advertised.listeners` correctly based on your networking setup.

For more details see https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/